# How can I store SpaceManager cpShape's in something like an array?

Tags: c, objective-c, nsmutablearray, chipmunk

I'm trying to create a squishy ball with Cocos2d and Chipmunk (via SpaceManager) using a bunch of rects all chained together then joined with springs to a central body.

[Something like these examples](http://www.theantenna.net/)

But in order to do this, i think I need to store all the cpShapes in an array after I've created them so I can then loop through the array to link them all together with constraints.

However, when i try to put cpShapes in an array, I get an error telling me it's an "incompatible pointer type". So... I either need to use something other than an array (I've tried a set, that didn't work either) or I need to do something to the shape to make it compatible... but what? OR I need another aproach.

Any ideas?

Here's the code so far should it be relevant...

```
- (id) init
{

    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {

        SpaceManager * spaceMgr = [[SpaceManager alloc] init];
        [spaceMgr addWindowContainmentWithFriction:1.0 elasticity:1.0 inset:cpv(5, 5)];

            // This is a layer that draws all the chipmunk shapes
        ChipmunkDrawingLayer *debug = [[ChipmunkDrawingLayer node] initWithSpace:spaceMgr.space];
        [self addChild:debug];

        int ballPeices = 10; // the number of peices I want my ball to be composed of
        int ballRadius = 100;
        float circum = M_PI * (ballRadius * 2);

        float peiceSize = circum / ballPeices;
        float angleIncrement = 360 / ballPeices;

        CGPoint origin = ccp(240, 160);
        float currentAngleIncrement = 0;

            NSMutableArray *peiceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ballPeices];

        for (int i = 0; i < ballPeices; i++) {

            float angleIncrementInRadians = CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(currentAngleIncrement);

            float xp = origin.x + ballRadius * cos(angleIncrementInRadians);
            float yp = origin.y + ballRadius * sin(angleIncrementInRadians);

                    // This is wrong, I need to figure out what's going on here.
            float peiceRotation = atan2( origin.y - yp, origin.x - xp);

            cpShape *currentPeice = [spaceMgr addRectAt:ccp(xp, yp) mass:1 width:peiceSize height:10 rotation:peiceRotation];

            currentAngleIncrement += angleIncrement;

                    [peiceArray addObject:currentPeice]; //!! incompatible pointer type

        }



        spaceMgr.constantDt = 0.9/55.0;
        spaceMgr.gravity = ccp(0,-980);
        spaceMgr.damping = 1.0;

    }

    return self;

}
```

Comment: where are you adding the spring constraints?  I don't see it

Comment: I've not gotten that far yet. I figure I need a way to access the shapes after they've been created. To do that, I need to get them into an array or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incompatible pointer type is easy to explain :)

`[NSMutableArray addObject]` is defined as such:

```
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject
```

So what is an `id` then?  Great question!  Remember, Objective-C is still C at it's core.  According to the [Objective-C Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW3)

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

That's great, now we know about `*id` but what about `id` itself?  That's what is referenced in the method signature.  For that, we have to look at [objc.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371.1/runtime/objc.h)

```
typedef id (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...);
```

Clearly, `cpSpace*` doesn't fit that, so you'll be getting incompatible pointer type if you try to put those into `NSMutableArray` using that message.

Comment: So if I can't put them in an array, what can I put them in? I can put other objects in an array.

Comment: You can put them inside anything that inherits from `NSObject`, then stow that in the `NSMutableArray`.  Sometimes this is referred to as "boxing"

Comment: Also, you can always just keep a plain old C array

Comment: NSValue was made for this http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `NSValue *theValue = [NSValue value:&myShape withObjCType:@encode(cpShape**)];`